# How to code swirl like table in HTML?

Tags: html

See this:

```
 _____ __
|_____|  |
|  |__|__|
|__|_____|
```

How to code it in HTML?

Comment: what have you tried? Are there fix dimensions or is it a flexible layout? :P

Comment: Make liberal use of the `colspan=""` attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `border="1"` is not very nice. You should do that in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>top left</td>
        <td rowspan=2>top right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2>lower left</td>
        <td>center</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan=2>lower right</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

It produces

[image]

Comment: Cool! Never seen that site :)

Answer (score 1):

use colspan and rowspan, and set height and width.

```
<table border=1 height=400 width=400>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>1</td>
    <td rowspan=2>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan=2>4</td>
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2>8</td>    
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/2b9K3/

```
  <table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2"></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I like the way the width is set for this one most by far from all the offered solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done pretty easily with `rowspans` and `colspans`.